# A First Person Style Camera for LWJGL (Mouse Support)

Tags: java, camera, lwjgl, frame-rate

I'm working on a 3D game in LWJGL, and I'd like to add a first person style camera with mouse support. I have one currently, but it's not smooth and doesn't work very well at all. I'd really like to have the window focused as well, so the mouse is engaged and not hovering over the window. How can I implement this?

Here is my current camera implementation:

```
public class Camera {

private Vector3f position = new Vector3f(0,5,0);
private float pitch = 10;
private float yaw;
private float roll;

private float speed = 0.2f;

public Camera() {

}

public void move() {

    yaw =  - (Display.getWidth() - Mouse.getX() / 4);
    pitch =  (Display.getHeight() / 1000) - Mouse.getY();

    if (pitch >= 90) {
        pitch = 90;
    }
    else if (pitch <= -90) {
        pitch = -90;
    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {

        position.z += -(float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw)) * speed;
        position.x += (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw)) * speed;

    }
    else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {

        position.z -= -(float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw)) * speed;
        position.x -= (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw)) * speed;

    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {

        position.z += (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw)) * speed;
        position.x += (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw)) * speed;

    }
    else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {

        position.z -= (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw)) * speed;
        position.x -= (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw)) * speed;

    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LSHIFT)) {

        position.y -= speed;

    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) {

        position.y += speed;

    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

public Vector3f getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public float getPitch() {
    return pitch;
}

public float getYaw() {
    return yaw;
}

public float getRoll() {
    return roll;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing integer division when calculating yaw and pitch, this is bad because the result will also be an integer. To change this you just have to make one value a float like this:

```
yaw =  - (Display.getWidth() - Mouse.getX() / 4f);
pitch =  (Display.getHeight() / 1000f) - Mouse.getY();
```

Now the result will be much more precise.

Although I reccomend to use this code to calculate your pitch and yaw:

```
float rotationSpeed = 1.0; //You probably need to change this factor
yaw -= Mouse.getDX() / rotationSpeed;
pitch += Mouse.getDY() / rotationSpeed;
```

getDX/Y() returns the movement on the x/y axis since last time getDX/Y() was called.

If you want to focus on the window just call Mouse.setGrabbed(true).